# can a closed question be voted?

Tags: discussion, voting

I'm not sure where to find an answer, but i asked an not-so-good question lately and it was closed...   that fine, thats ok.. i apprechiate that it has been closed...

...after my question has been closed i got some downvotes on that question and i was curious how that would be useful? to make my question more concrete: **"how can a closed question be voted? (downvoted)"**

what use would that be? it has already been closed and afterwards it is downvoted even further? am i expected to delete that question?

Comment: when looking at my profile it's obviously http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/185599/external-interface-for-civ5 hehe - no problem with closing that, honestly (see discussion)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I imagine your quarrel is that the downvotes affect your reputation on the website. If this is the case, you can simply delete the question and you'll regain that lost reputation.

As for the purpose or "use," a downvoted question is an indication that the general population of active users does not find the question to be a good fit for the website. While closing a question can just be a matter of technicalities and pedantry, a closed question can sometimes still receive upvotes as users may still find it to be a valuable source of information. Upvotes and downvotes, however, are simply a means of approval and disapproval. Closing a question doesn't lock it at its last state of approval/disapproval when it was first closed. Users are allowed to continue expressing their opinion (and even providing answers and comments, usually), regardless of the question's state.

Comment: Thanks for clearing that out `Closing a question doesn't lock it` is a good explanation for my issue ^^ i referre to http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/256559/should-i-delete-my-question-if-it-is-closed where it says 'don't delete "stuipd" questions... so this is somehow contraproductive ^^ thanks for your response

Comment: i think that a 'stupid question' can be a good example for how to **not do** it and therefore should stay... is there any use in downvotig it further?

Comment: especially when you consider http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/5498/a-close-vote-is-not-a-super-downvote-please-dont-use-it-as-one (sorry for *spamming* into your answer here, i think those links clear out what dilemma can be)

Comment: @MartinFrank As for keeping it as an "example," there's not much point of that. Did you see any examples of bad questions before asking yours? Typically, people don't lurk on poor questions before asking their own. And the last thing you linked isn't relevant. It discusses the difference between a downvote and a close. Your question was both closed and downvoted because it fits for both actions.

Comment: @MartinFrank Actually, since your question is closed and negatively scored, with no positive answers, the roomba will automatically delete it, and you'll get your rep back.  This usually happens roughly ten days after it gets closed.  That's why you won't see a lot of old, unacceptable questions; they get automatically culled.

Comment: OK, i must take your answer as to be true! i for myself stumbled across some "stupid answers" and i had some learning from them... but your Points also have very good reasons to be true so i cannot argue with that i think you three have a correct view of post and i apply your point of view!  thank you all very much for clearing that out! it was a very good conversation so far and i wish to keep that up further!!! i dont want to be impolite but ill accept this answer (and those good cooments), close this thread, and keep that in mind for further answers/questions ^^

Comment: @Frank excuse when i have to add another question, when how will the cleanup happen? i have never had the opportunity to see this automatism work... i would be glad to see wht&when will happen...

Comment: @MartinFrank It usually happens ten days after your question was closed.  Since that happened on the 30th, it will probably take a few more days before it gets auto-deleted.

Comment: thank you for proving this  information! i was not so sure where to find such information as fast as you did. i'll be looking orward to see what will happen, keep up the good gaming @Frank